# Почему QTextEdit не сохраняет форматирование текста?

Tags: python, html, pyqt5, gui, qtextedit

Написал текстовый редактор с использованием `QTextEdit`, с возможностью форматировать: текст, шрифт, размер, жирность, наклон, подчеркивание, выравнивание по сторонам.

Все работает, но проблема заключается в том, что сохранив написанный отформатированный текст сохраняется только сам текст, а форматирование нет.

При открытии данного текстового файла отображается обычный текст, в чем проблема?

Comment: имеет смысл поместить тут часть кода (с одной функцией, например)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QTextEdit` — это расширенная программа просмотра/редактора *WYSIWYG*,
поддерживающая форматирование расширенного текста с использованием тегов
в стиле `HTML` или формата `Markdown`.

`QTextEdit` может отображать изображения, списки и таблицы.
Если текст слишком велик для просмотра в области просмотра текстового редактора,
появятся полосы прокрутки. 
**`Редактирование текста может загружать как`** обычный текст, так и **`файлы с форматированным текстом.`**
Форматированный текст можно описать с помощью подмножества разметки `HTML 4`.

> [**html : QString**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#html-prop)
>
> Это свойство предоставляет интерфейс HTML для текста редактирования текста.
>
> **`toHtml()`** возвращает текст редактирования текста в формате html.
>
> **`setHtml()`** изменяет текст редактирования текста. 
> Любой предыдущий текст удаляется, а история отмены/повтора очищается.
> Входной текст интерпретируется как форматированный текст в формате html. 
> `currentCharFormat()` также сбрасывается, если только `textCursor()` уже не находится
> в начале документа.
>
> Примечание: Вызывающий должен убедиться, что текст правильно декодирован,
> когда `QString`, содержащий `HTML`, создается и передается в `setHtml()`.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, все заработало. Оказалось при сохранении текста нужно было вместо toPlainText указать toHtml

Comment: @PoisonBH пожалуйста.  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour